# PHP Вопросы по (Сессий) Создание несколько сессий на странице?

Tags: php, сессия

новичок в PHP сейчас разбираю как работают сессии, есть некоторые не понятные детали, которые я не могу найти на просторах всемирной паутины, был бы очень рад если бы более опытные разъяснили что к чему.
Вопросы:

1. session_start(); - создает сеанс, или нужно для создание сеанса?
2. Можно ли создать несколько сессий на одной странице к примеру для анонимно пользователя и
   залогиненого, если да, то как это правильней сделать, можно ли примеры из практики.
3. $_SESSION - Является массивом который содержит *сессии*, или это массив который содержит переменные одной сессии, на многих сайтах информация описана по разному.
4. Какие способы передачи сессий с одной страницы на другую есть, к примеру -> я делаю сессию авторизации, при переходе на другую страницу я хочу создать новую сессию, но так же что бы я мог работать как с прошлой сессий, так же и с новой $_SESSION - будет массивом для новой сессии.

Это пока что основные вопросы которые мне не дают покоя, искал информацию но слишком большая каша и на каждом сайте написано либо заумно, либо по разному.. Будут благодарен помощи)

Comment: 1, 3, 4 - [session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)... 2 - у анонимного будет своя сессия, у залогиненного тоже своя